# Issues with Tailwind CSS in NextJS pages directory

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind styles not working

I am having a issue getting Tailwind styles to apply to any of the components I have in the /pages directory in NextJS. If I use the same component outside of the pages directory, it works as expected and the styles are applied. If I navigate to the component on a route such as /my-component where there is a
my-component.tsx in the /pages directory, the styles are not applied. I have tried everything and walked through all the tutorials without any luck. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

My tailwind.config.js file is below:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",

        // Or if using `src` directory:
        "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: My tailwind.config.js looks slightly different: 
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}".

Maybe try changing your ```"./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"``` to ```"./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",```

Comment: Please add your `css` and `_app.tsx` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed all steps provided by TailwindCSS?

They state on their website these steps:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

tailwind.config.js should look like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Go to globals.css and add these lines:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Run:
`npm run dev`

Apply some Tailwind classes to root component:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Hello world!
    </h1>
  )
}
```

It must work, you just missed some step.